# Html menu shifted to right - want left

Tags: html, css, menu

Here is a simple html menu but it shifts to the right a little and I can't figure it out. I want it inline with the "Welcome" title. I'm using Firefox and I'm not sure if it's just a Firefox issue or not? I read padding and margins for ul should be 0 and they are here and it seems to make no difference.

[image: Menu Shifted]

```css
code,
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #600;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #F8BC27;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>

  <h1><a href=/index.html class=logo>Welcome</a></h1>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/posts/docs-1.html">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/posts/tags.html">Tags</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/newsletters/docs-1.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/search.html">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet and consolidated the styles

Comment: _I'm using Firefox and I'm not sure if it's just a Firefox issue or not?_ this can easily be found out by testing with other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Reset

```
* { padding:0; margin:0; }
```

and have

```
ul.menu {
  ...
  padding: 20px;
```

and

```
.menu li a {
   ...
   padding: 0 20px 0 0; 
   ...
```

and add padding to the UL, which IS the .menu and not a child element

```css
* { padding:0; margin:0; }

code,
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

ul.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #600;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0; 
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #F8BC27;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <h1><a href=/index.html class=logo>Welcome</a></h1>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/posts/docs-1.html">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/posts/tags.html">Tags</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/newsletters/docs-1.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/search.html">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What about the spacing between those lines. Seems to have been lost.

Comment: @mplungjan, I believe this to be incorrect.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is the way you are targeting your menu ul element.  simply use .menu and NOT .menu ul

```css
code,
pre {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.menu  {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #600;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #F8BC27;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>

  <h1><a href=/index.html class=logo>Welcome</a></h1>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/posts/docs-1.html">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/posts/tags.html">Tags</a></li>
    <li><a href="/indexes/newsletters/docs-1.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/search.html">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The menu is not left justified under the header so less correct than mine

Comment: @mplungjan, I believe you are incorrect, again!  The padding comes from the css on .menu li a which is supplied by OP

Comment: If OP want the padding-left to be 0 on the LI then it is not specified correctly by OP

Comment: I notice in your updated answer you have the same as I do in regards to the padding